# Facebook API: Get all posts made in common location within timeframe

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm wondering if it's possible to get all public posts made in a certain location within a certain period of time. For instance, get all posts made in New York, New York, between 6:00 AM yesterday and 6:00 AM today. Is this doable using Facebook's API? I'm quite new to it and am unsure how to access data from any starting point other than a specific user ID.

I assume one would start with the geocoordinates or location ID as one parameter, and filter from there? I could be wrong.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. There is no endpoint for this type of search.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/v2.4#search